# Android UI: "Smart" centering?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a UI element (a single line of text) that I want horizontally centered with respect to the overall device -- unless/until it collides with other UI elements in the given view group / layout.  At that point I'd like it to be either centered in the space remaining or pegged as close to being centered overall as possible without colliding.  [When there's finally not enough space, then I want to use ellipses.]

Is there any way to achieve this using just standard Android layouts?

I'm currently achieving this via code that adjusts layout constraints when the view group's width changes, the text changes, or related UI elements become visible/invisible.  It works fine, but I can't help thinking that some layout should just do this for me.

Comment: add a mockup to your question

Comment: "unless/until it collides with other UI elements in the given view group / layout" -- shouldn't that be knowable at compile time? If it is not, because those other UI elements change in size or something... I'm not sure that there's a good way of accomplishing your desired rule, outside of a custom `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @commonsware I think @rupps answer would work, if we replace the `Button` with a `ViewGroup` and insert more `View`s to that child `ViewGroup` during runtime. Thoughts?

Comment: @CommonsWare The text size length is not known at compile time (think equivalent of a web page title in a browser).

Comment: @Pooya Rather than a mockup, I will note a clarifying example. If I have only a text view and a button and the button takes up 33% of the screen width (including padding) and is at the far right of the view, then I'd want the text centered with respect to the overall device width -- unless it (including its padding) is wider than 33% of the screen and would thus collide with the button. In case of a collision then the text could be centered in the remaining space instead (as with a weighted Linear layout).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a weighted horizontal `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="i am centered"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

    <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="another widget"/>
     .
     .
     .
</LinearLayout>
```

The `TextView` with **width 0dp** and **weight 1** will use the remaining horizontal space.

You can add additional widgets to the `LinearLayout`, and the `TextView` will always take the remaining space.

For example, if you change the Visibility of the `Button` to `GONE`, you'll see the `TextView` will expand to use the whole width. Similarly, if you programmatically add new widgets to the `LinearLayout`, the available space for the `TextView` will adjust.

You can further add `ellipsize` options to control what happens when the text does not fit in the `TextView` size.

Comment: Doesn't that center the text view in the space remaining after the button's width is accounted for?

What I need is to center it in the entire overall space unless it actually collides with the button.

Comment: Oh... I see... Then AFAIK you'll need to do it programmatically. Maybe `CoordinatorLayout` with behaviours for the `Button` and `TextView` can help, or as @Commonsware suggest, go for a custom `ViewGroup`

Comment: So I got what I wanted from a RelativeLayout and a series of listeners and overrides.  The result is not a general, reusable component, but that's alright.  I was just really hoping that I was missing a layout that would handle such complexity without extra coding.